# Does .NET intermediate language have stack manipulation functions?

Tags: .net, stack, intermediate-language

Probably a dumb question, but does MSIL have general Forth-like functions for manipulating data on its stack? (For example, DUP, SWAP, etc.)

Comment: What did reading the documentation tell you?

Comment: It is a stack-based language, like Forth, but focus on *intermediate*.  You don't program in it and you don't execute it.  There's Pop, Dup and a bunch of LdXxx that push.  That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IL is a stack-based language, so most instructions manipulate the stack in some way. `dup` is a IL instruction, but it doesn't have `swap` (you have to use a local variable)

Answer (score 0):

[Partition III of the CIL](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) will give you all the information you want.

Section 3.33 is for DUP, for example.